# How does `GROUP BY` determine which aggregation method to use?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'd been having trouble with the `"Column 'examplecolumn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."` error for a while and, much to my exasperation, the eventual fix was to add every offending column to a `GROUP BY` clause. After doing some research I still don't entirely get why this throws an error instead of giving you a very ugly table, but that's not the important part.

What is important is that according to my research, `GROUP BY` merges identical rows based on the column that you pass to it. Choosing an appropriate method to add the data together. Out of curiosity, I duplicated my existing query and made one small change. If my understanding of how GROUP BY works was correct it should have given me the same output:

The original:

```
SELECT [ProductName]
   ,[CompanyName]
   ,[CategoryID] AS 'CategoryName'
   ,SUM(Quantity) AS 'Total Ordered'
FROM [Order Details] AS t1
INNER JOIN Products AS t2
   ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
INNER JOIN Suppliers AS t3
   ON t2.SupplierID = t3.SupplierID
GROUP BY ProductName, CategoryID, CompanyName
```

The altered version:

```
SELECT [ProductName]
   ,[CompanyName]
   ,[CategoryID] AS 'CategoryName'
   ,Quantity AS 'Total Ordered'
FROM [Order Details] AS t1
INNER JOIN Products AS t2
   ON t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
INNER JOIN Suppliers AS t3
   ON t2.SupplierID = t3.SupplierID
GROUP BY ProductName, CategoryID, CompanyName, Quantity
```

I had believed that the `GROUP BY` clause would use SUM(Quantity) as it's aggregation method. It did not. In fact, other than remove the error message, I'm not sure what it did.

Here's a screenshot of the output:[image: output of the two queries]

It's obvious my understanding of `GROUP BY` is wrong. I had believed that the aggregation method was determined by the type of data found in the column that was listed. Since that is not the case, how DOES `GROUP BY` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` indicates the columns that will *not* be aggregated. As such, every unique combination of values in those columns will produce one row of output.

All of the remaining columns you want in your output *will* need to be in aggregates - but that's what the error message tells you - it wants *you* to tell the server which aggregate is appropriate.

Comment: On a slight tangent, this requirement to include every non-aggregated column in `GROUP BY`, *even when I'm already grouping by the primary key of the same table*, is one of my pet peeves with SQL. It's tedious, it obscures the intent of the grouping, and by needlessly duplicating information and cluttering up the query, it makes it more likely for the next person editing the query to introduce subtle bugs. The database damn well *could* tell from the key constraints that those columns will never have multiple values inside a group; it *shouldn't* require me to redundantly specify that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - now I'm curious - if you're `GROUP`ing by a known-distinct set of columns, what *aggregates* are you computing?

Comment: Typically, something on another table that has a many-to-one relationship with the table whose primary key I'm grouping by. Something like `SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName, COUNT(EmployeeId) AS EmployeeCount, WebsiteURL FROM Companies JOIN Employees USING (CompanyId) GROUP BY CompanyId`, where `CompanyId` is the primary key for the `Companies` table. (This query will fail on SQL Server, of course, because I left out the redundant columns `CompanyName` and `WebsiteURL` from the `GROUP BY`.)

Comment: I think I get it, more experience will probably make this more clear to me. Thanks. I'll mark this as the answer, it makes things a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation method is not decided by GROUP BY clause. It should be given in SQL. The second SQL query just gives you unique combinations which can be formed by values of columns GROUP BY clause.